# Is there a Hudud punishment for blaming someone on things he hasn't done?

Tags: punishment, hudud

Is there a Hudud punishment for blaming someone on things (bad things like crimes, haram actions and so on) he hasn't done? (English is not my first, and I think it is called defamation in English. Please correct me if wrong).

I heard that punishment for this kind of actions is cutting off person's tongue. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no, there is no Hudud punishment for slandering. One exception is Qadhf, which is making false accusation of immoral actions. In that case yes there is Hudud punishment for it but it is whipping not cutting off tongue.

> An-Noor verse 4 : And those who accuse chaste women, and produce not
>   four witnesses, flog them with eighty stripes, and reject their
>   testimony forever. They indeed are the Fasiqun (liars, rebellious,
>   disobedient to Allah).

Comment: Sorry, is there such punishment at all, cutting off person's tongue?

Comment: @Bahrom No, unless it is in qesas e.g. if someone cut another person's tongue then the victim may seek revenge.